# How to debug Scala in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, configuration, vscode-debugger, scala-metals

I've created a `.scala` file and opened it in VS Code. I have Scala (Metals) installed which is a VS Code extension which advertises including a debugger. According to [its documentation](https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/vscode/), it should integrate with VS Code's debugging features. But I can only execute my file from within VS Code with the *Run Code* (Control+Alt+N) command. Issuing either *Start Debugging* (F5) or *Run Without Debigging* (Control+F5) does nothing. The code lenses mentioned in the article don't appear either. Neither does the *Import build* prompt. Additionally, some Metals' commands don't work, resulting in an error message. E.g. for *Run doctor* (which I attempted, having read it's supposed to fix errors that may be present in my configuration) it says:

> Command 'Metals: Run doctor' resulted in an error (command 'metals.doctor-run' not found)

I've tried reinstalling Metals but to no avail.

My software versions are:

- Scala 2.13.6-20210529-211702-unknown
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
- sbt 1.5.5
- 5.15.2-2-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Nov 13 19:25:38 UTC 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Visual Studio Code 1.62.3
- Scala (Metals) v1.10.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have run into an issue described here:
https://github.com/scalameta/metals-vscode/issues/213

I had the same problem on Win environment - no one Metals command was recognized( E.g. "Run doctor")..

Instead of open just *.scala* file in VS Code try to open a project directory.